# Loading image from smb server

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi

Using Ubuntu, I'm trying to load images from a smb server(raspberry pi)

```
Mat img = imread("smb://192.168.1.8/share/share/image.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

But it's failing; the image cannot be loaded. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try dropping any firewalls between source and sink.

Comment: Have you mounted the smb share and configured smb.conf correctly?

Comment: yes of course and this worked on windows but it in ubuntu